# How to use Map collection to associate between Account and Opportunity

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

How to write a trigger that creates 10 identical Opportunities whenever an Account with more than 99 employees is created. Make sure all Opportunities are associated with the Account. Use any values for the fields on the Opportunities and to work with Map collection.

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accList AND NumberOfEmployees > 99]);       
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accountMap.keySet()]) {
                Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
                opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
                opp.Name = acc.Name;
                opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
                opp.StageName = 'Prospecting'; 
                oppList.add(opp);
            }
    }   
    
    insert oppList;
```

This is the code that I've written and I just want to be without nested loops, because the records when are inserted the operation is not that good optimized and it's not good practice for a trigger.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Is this a hiring or interview question?)

Comment: Actaully it's normal task that I want to make it without nested for loops and make it with Map Collection. That's all, just to see a code

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen directly after a new Account record is created, then you would have it called during the After Insert event on the Account object (make sure to not include code directly in the trigger, use a handler class to contain logic.)

You don't have to query Account records because all of those fields are available in the Trigger.new list in AFTER insert (including the IDs for the new accounts). See code example below.

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();    
for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
    if (acc.NumberOfEmployees > 99) {
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                AccountId = acc.Id,
                Name = acc.Name,
                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                StageName = 'Prospecting'
            );
            oppList.add(opp);
        }
    }
}
insert oppList;
```

This solves what you asked, but are you just looking for other code examples on how to work with Maps, instantiating SObjects, etc?

Comment: This code is with nested loop again. It's bad practice for a trigger. As I asked I'm looking for option without nested and working with Map collection.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a loop that runs through the Trigger.new list... that's a common aspect in any Apex Trigger. It's SOQL queries and DML statements within a loop that you need to avoid. 

Creating a map isn't going to add any value for you, especially if creating a Map of Account records that's already provided from the Trigger.newMap collection. These records (and all fields) are already accessible, but you seem determined to add queries and build maps you don't need. I have a feeling you're trying to experiment with using maps more effectively but have not picked a good use case.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Try the following code : using maps             
        
        Trigger InsertoppournitiesforEmp99 on Account (after insert ,after update)  {
                     if(trigger.Isafter) {
                    if(trigger.Insert || trigger.update) {
                    Createoppournities newOpps = new Createoppournities ();
                    newOpps.insert10oppournities(Trigger.new);
                    }
                    }
                    }
                
                Helper class :
public class Createoppournities {
                public  void insert10oppournities(List<Account> accountlist) {
        List<opportunity> insertOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
            Map<Id,List<Opportunity>> addOppurnitieswithaccount = new Map<Id,List<Opportunity>>();
             for(Account acc : accountList) {
            if(acc.Number_Of_Employees__c > 99 ) {
            addOppurnitieswithaccount.put(acc.Id, null);
            }
             }
        
        for(Id empAccounts : addOppurnitieswithaccount.keyset()) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
                 opp.AccountId = empAccounts;
                 opp.Name = 'test Oppournity'+i;
                 opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
                 opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                 insertOpps .add(opp);
          }
        }
        if(insertOpps.size() > 0 ) {
        insert insertOpps ; 
        }
}
}
```